# ipage: the default page does not direct to index.html

Tags: html, .htaccess

I just started developing web page, hosted by iPage.
I wanted to publish my own index.html instead of what was given.
But, when I actually enter the page, it directs to the previously changed page, which does not exist anymore.

I can access index.html, but only when I manually type in the address as epseattle.com/index.html.

How do I fix this?
I have tried fix on htaccess already.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. Rename the original index.html which was available earlier in your web root to something like this index_1.html. And then try http://www.epseattle.com.

If the above not works, kindly post with your .htaccess file content.

Answer (score 0):

In your .Htaccess file, try this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Try switching off buffering on the iPage server (you can do this via their site).  You will also need to do the same on the browser.  Your changes should then be immediately visible. Remember, this is for development only and severely restricts performance of your server.